# Which of these deductions are true about the simulator and the adversary?

Tags: protocol-design, terminology, protocol-analysis, security-definition

Which of these deductions make sense?

1. The *simulator* is actually being run *by the adversary*. It makes sense that the adversary *initializes* the simulator (which is just a program) with the input that the corrupted party (also just a program) will use.
2. The *adversary* is actually being run *by the simulator*, and the simulator (which is just a program) will give the adversary (which is just a program)  the information it needs.
3. We just should consider the adversary as a *black-box* that the simulator has an access to it and *vice versa*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 is true. So 1 is obviously false. 3 is not true because there exists something called non black-box simulation (see [Baoz Barak's thesis](https://www.boazbarak.org/Papers/thesis.pdf)).